# In this setting, why is the inverse function not continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Definition for continuity used here:

$f: A \rightarrow B$ is continuous if given any $x$ in $A$ and any neighborhood $N$ of the point $f(x)$ in $B$, the set $f^{-1}(N)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $A$.

[image: problem]

I am trying to understand why the inverse function $g = f^-1$ is not continuous.
OK... $f$ maps $0$ to $1 + i \cdot 0$ So $g$ maps  $1 + i \cdot 0$ to $0$.

So I think it must be because of the following. If we take a neighborhood $N$ (on the unit circle) of the complex number $z = 1 + i \cdot 0$ then we need to show that the set $g(N)$ is not a neighborhood of the point $0$ ( from the real interval $[0, 1)$ ).

But why is it not a neighborhood, it seems like a neighborhood to me?! I think $g(N)$ has the form something like $[0, 0+\epsilon_1) \cup (1-\epsilon_2, 1)$ which seems like a neighborhood of $0$ given that our whole space/sub-space of the reals is $[0, 1)$

Or... do I need to pick another $z$ to show that $g$ is not continuous?! I doubt it.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's the other way around... I need to pick a neighborhood of the real point g(z) for some $z \in C$ and show that $g^{−1}(N)=f(N)$ is not a neighborhood of z?! Is that right? There's some double back and forth here which is confusing me, it seems. And I guess that $g(z)$ has to be the real point $0$ and the $z$ which I need to pick is of course $1 + i \cdot 0$

Comment: Yes, that's it.  A function is continuous iff the inverse image of an open set is open, but we're saying that $f^{-1}$ isn't continuous, so we need to find an open $G \subseteq [0,1)$ such that $f(G)$ isn't open, and $[0,\varepsilon)$ works.

Comment: The concepts open and closed are not yet introduced. Also about $[0, \epsilon)$ I still don't see how it works, I will think some more.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh, I see $g^{-1}([0, \epsilon))$ contains only points with $Imag \ge 0$ from the unit circle, and not any points with $Imag \lt 0$. So it's not a neighborhood (on the unit circle) of the complex number $1$ . Right?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for the confirmation of this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Now if the inverse map were continuous, then [0,1) would
be the continuous image of a compact set, hence compact.
As [0,1) is not compact, continuity would contradict the above theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I needed something elementary written in more details... but I get the idea. Could you verify the detailed proof I posted here as an answer? I just tried to make the proof as detailed as possible so that I it is convincing enough for my own self :)

Comment: I see no need to belabor a problem that is easy to solve. @peter.petrov

Comment: Oh, this is so kind of you :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$f : [0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$

Obviously $f$ is a bijection from  $[0, 1)$ to the unit circle $B$ from $\mathbb{C}$.

We want to prove that the inverse function

$g: B \rightarrow [0, 1)$

is not continuous.

Let's take the point $z_0 = 1 + 0 \cdot i \in B$ and $x_0=0 \in [0,1)$.

Clearly $f(x_0) = z_0$

$\Rightarrow g(z_0) = x_0$

Let's pick a small $\epsilon$ neighborhood (in the real interval $[0, 1)$) of the point $g(z_0) = x_0 = 0$ and denote this neighborhood by $N$.

$\Rightarrow N = [0, \epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Now by definition the set $g^{-1}(N) $ is the set $ \{z\ |\ g(z) \in N\} = M$

i.e. it is the set of those points from the unit cirlce which $g$ sends into $N$.

$\Rightarrow$ $M = \{ z = e^{2 \pi i x}\ |\ x \in [0, \epsilon)\}$ which is a tiny piece of the unit circle which lies in 1st quadrant. Since M does not contain the respective complex points from 4th quadrant ( I mean the points $\{ z = e^{2 \pi i (-x)}\ |\ x \in (0, \epsilon)\}$ ), this set $M$ is not a neighborhood of the point $z_0 = 1$ from the unit circle $B$.

$\Rightarrow$ the set $g^{-1}(N)$ is not a neighborhood of the point $z_0 = 1$ in the unit circle $B$

$\Rightarrow$ $g$ is not continuous at the point $z_0$

Comment: @saulspatz Could you please check this proof? I intentionally wrote it in detail.

Comment: I think you mean $4$th quadrant where you said $3$rd quadrant, bu otherwise it looks ok.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes. Thanks a lot for reading it through.

Comment: $[0,1/2)$ is a nbhd of $0$ in the space $[0,1)$...If $z\in  f^{-1}[0,1/2)$ then $Im(z)\ge 0.$ But a nbhd $M$ of $1(=f^{-1}(0))$ in the space $C$ must contain some $z$ with $Im(z)<0$.... because for some $r>0$ we have $M\supset C\cap \{z: |z-1|<r\}.$